# jQuery maphilight using "onclick" method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using maphilight plugin, it applies to images with a 'usemap' attribute, and outlines the areas defined in their map on mouseover.

(documentation here: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/).

I would to trigger the hilight effect with the onClick event instead of "onmouseover".

I do this:

```
jQuery('.area').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var data = jQuery(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
    jQuery(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    
});
```

It works correctly but I want to erase the hilight effect when I make a new click.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for this part of the code and change:

```
            $(map).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight').find('area[coords]')
            .bind('mouseover.maphilight', mouseover)
            .bind('mouseout.maphilight', function(e) { clear_canvas(canvas); });
```

To this:

```
            $(map).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight').find('area[coords]')
            .bind('click.maphilight', mouseover)
            .bind('mouseout.maphilight', function(e) { clear_canvas(canvas); });
```

Changing the "mouseover" event to "click" will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code, it looks like the event `mouseout.maphilight` is bound to the hilight map which will clear the canvas. I would guess you can trigger that event to clear it. It looks like you will probably have to track the state yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code> 
$('.mianchor').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var colorx = $(this).attr('title');
        var data = {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        data.stroke = 'none';
        data.strokeWidth = 0.0000001;
        data.strokeColor = colorx;
        data.fillColor = colorx; // Sample color
        data.fillOpacity = 1;
        $('#mapa').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');         
    });
```